# Optimisation of accessing const members of const struct

Tags: c, constants, compiler-optimization

I have a struct and global variable like this

```c
struct X {
    int a;
    int const b;
} x = (X) { .a = 4, .b = 5 };
```

The idea is that `a` should be mutable, while `b` is not
Also, x here is unreassignable (you cannot reassign it `x = (X) { .a = 8, .b = 9 }`)

Now, I was hoping that accessing `b` would be optimized at compile-time
so instead of accessing `x` every time, it is replaced like macro

I was interested: Does it optimize, under what conditions (what GCC arguments)

Comment: What did your experiments reveal? You can look into the generated assembly, or let GCC generate assembler source.

Comment: interesting topic, however, what is the question?

Comment: @thebusybee I don't know how to read assembly

Comment: @tstanisl Question is stated in the last sentence. Does it get optimized?

Comment: So you are asking us to compile your not provided [mre] in multiple variants of options, which you don't tell us, with a compiler not specified exactly, and interpret the result for you? Really? Uhm, quite difficult. Sorry, my crystal ball is still in quarantaine. -- It might help you much more, if you get a beginner's level of understanding assembler. -- Why at all do you want to know? Do you want to solve a special optimization problem?

Comment: it should but it looks that the latest GCC does not take optimize it even for `-O3`. See https://godbolt.org/z/Ejq43P3h3

Comment: Bare `X` is not a synonym for `struct X` in C, although it *is* in C++. Please figure out which language you are using.

Comment: as @tstanisl said, it does not in gcc. But on the link he provided, I noticed it does optimize if the whole struct variable is const `const struct X x`. I'm kinda interested in other compilers too.